# How to speed up Ajax Calls using client side scripting

Tags: javascript, ajax, magento, jquery

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

[image]

this one i wrote this using ajax functions  for appearing dynamic dropdown values its taking too much time more than 1 min.

how can i make this as very fast ?

any ideas ?

Comment: Is it the ajax call taking a long time or is it the server taking a long time to build the result? Did you try caching the result so you don't have to build the result every call

Answer (score 0):

If number of all items in those 3 select boxes are somehow small (~100) then its much faster and easier to load all options with the page in JS array and on change of first select box you just get the related items from the array

Answer (score 0):

i believe there is no way in making AJAX call faster...
but i would suggest to show something like loading image on the product dropdown, until all ajax call get success....

use ajaxStart() ajaxStop() to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just load the data needed once the page begins loading. And then just display all the applicable options onchange of the select boxes. However, if you have a lot of data, this may not be the wisest solution. If you have a large dataset and commonly clicked options, you could by default load the more commonly selected options as the page loads.